# Datetime rolling count per category in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation, datetimeindex

Starting from a DataFrame with a `date` and `user` column, I'd like to add a third `count_past_5_days` column to indicate the rolling count of occurrences of each row's user during the past 5 days:

| date | user | count_past_5_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | abc | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | def | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | abc | 2 |
| 2020-01-03 | abc | 3 |
| 2020-01-04 | abc | 4 |
| 2020-01-04 | def | 2 |
| 2020-01-04 | ghi | 1 |
| 2020-01-05 | abc | 5 |
| 2020-01-06 | abc | 5 |
| 2020-01-07 | abc | 5 |

I've tried the following:

```py
df.set_index('date').rolling('5D')['user'].count()
```

But this gets the total count for the past five rolling days, not just for the specific user of the current row. How to get this rolling count, for each row's specific user only?

Comment: You can set a new column = df. set index groupby transform (func) and define the func to be the rolling count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you can chain `rolling` on `groupby`:

```
df.set_index('date').groupby('user')['user']\
  .rolling('5D')\
  .count()\
  .rename('count_past_5_days')\
  .reset_index()\
  .sort_values('date')
```

Output:

```
  user       date  count_past_5_days
0  abc 2020-01-01                1.0
1  def 2020-01-01                1.0
2  abc 2020-01-02                2.0
3  abc 2020-01-03                3.0
4  abc 2020-01-04                4.0
5  def 2020-01-04                2.0
6  ghi 2020-01-04                1.0
7  abc 2020-01-05                5.0
8  abc 2020-01-06                5.0
9  abc 2020-01-07                5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a sum across 'dummy' column whose values are all 1. This is the same approach that `pd.crosstab` uses under the hood- though we can name our output column directly.

```py
out = (
    df.assign(count_past_5_days=1)
    .groupby('user')
    .rolling('5D', on='date')['count_past_5_days']
    .sum()
)

print(out)
user  date      
abc   2020-01-01    1.0
      2020-01-02    2.0
      2020-01-03    3.0
      2020-01-04    4.0
      2020-01-05    5.0
      2020-01-06    5.0
      2020-01-07    5.0
def   2020-01-01    1.0
      2020-01-04    2.0
ghi   2020-01-04    1.0
Name: count_past_5_days, dtype: float64
```

This outputs a series whose values correspond to what you want. If you want your output to visually align with your input you can use any of the following...

- `out.sort_index(level='date').reset_index()`
- `out.reset_index().sort_values('date')`
- `out.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df).swaplevel()).reset_index()`

Note that option 3 will preserve the original ordering of your data if it happens to not be sorted.

```py
>>> out.sort_index(level='date').reset_index()
  user       date  count_past_5_days
0  abc 2020-01-01                1.0
1  def 2020-01-01                1.0
2  abc 2020-01-02                2.0
3  abc 2020-01-03                3.0
4  abc 2020-01-04                4.0
5  def 2020-01-04                2.0
6  ghi 2020-01-04                1.0
7  abc 2020-01-05                5.0
8  abc 2020-01-06                5.0
9  abc 2020-01-07                5.0
```